# iMac external display (EA232WMi) won't sleep

Tags: imac, display

I'm using an iMac 11,3 (27 inch, mid 2010) with an external display (an [NEC EA232WMi](http://www.necdisplay.com/p/desktop-monitors/ea232wmi-bk?type=support)).

Over the past week or so (beginning just prior to 10.9.2), when the iMac's display sleeps, the external display won't stay asleep.

It keeps waking up.

I can see the power indicator repeatedly going back and forth between the "on" and "energy save" modes. When it wakes, it shows its usual message about not receiving any video input signal. The iMac's internal display doesn't (visibly) do anything at all.

It doesn't seem to be related to any apps-- if I reboot the iMac and leave it there at the login screen until the display sleeps, the same thing happens.

This only happens when the display is off but the iMac is still awake. When the iMac sleeps, everything seems normal.

If I move the external display to a different Mac (which is also running 10.9.2), the display sleeps normally, so it seems to be specific to the iMac.

I did an SMC reset and even zapped the PRAM (yes, voodoo) but they had no effect. What can I look at to figure out why the iMac keeps waking the external display?

Additional: Wondering if this might be related to an external device, I tried unplugging everything from USB. No change. Turned off Bluetooth? No change.

**Update** with some requested information:

1. Console logs. All that I get is the following. In this test, the main display slept at 10:10 AM and the external display problem appeared. I let it continue until 10:16 AM. These are all the messages that appeared in Console.

   ```
   3/15/14 10:10:14.227 AM WindowServer[127]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x7fa8028e4910(2001)
   3/15/14 10:10:14.253 AM WindowServer[127]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x7fa8028e4910(2001)
   3/15/14 10:10:14.581 AM WindowServer[127]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x7fa8028e4910(2001)
   3/15/14 10:16:10.580 AM WindowServer[127]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
   3/15/14 10:16:10.582 AM WindowServer[127]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [59971881496111]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
   ```
2. System report "Graphics" data. Looks OK to me, let me know if you see anything that seems wrong.

   ```
   ATI Radeon HD 5750:

     Chipset Model:    ATI Radeon HD 5750
     Type: GPU
     Bus:  PCIe
     PCIe Lane Width:  x16
     VRAM (Total): 1024 MB
     Vendor:   ATI (0x1002)
     Device ID:    0x68a1
     Revision ID:  0x0000
     ROM Revision: 113-B9710C-238
     EFI Driver Version:   01.00.417
     Displays:
   iMac:
     Display Type: LCD
     Resolution:   2560 x 1440
     Pixel Depth:  32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
     Main Display: Yes
     Mirror:   Off
     Online:   Yes
     Built-In: Yes
   EA232WMi:
     Resolution:   1920 x 1080 @ 60Hz (1080p)
     Pixel Depth:  32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
     Display Serial Number:    1X312924NA  
     Mirror:   Off
     Online:   Yes
     Rotation: Supported
     Connection Type:  DisplayPort
     Television:   Yes
   ```

**Update 2**

In case it helps, I uploaded a [system profile of my iMac](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a1b6b4898350b42377a6) which I generated using `system_profiler -detailLevel mini`.

**Update 3**

Since @Buscar웃 is deleting their answer, I'll add these details here:

- "Wake on Network" is disabled
- There's no screen lock (no password required to wake the Mac)
- All sharing services have been disabled (several were active, including screen sharing and DVD sharing, bu disabling them had no effect).

**Update 4**

In case it's useful, the cycle time of the wake/sleep process is 8 seconds. Meaning, if I watch the display and its power indicator, this cycle repeats every 8 seconds:

- Monitor shows its "no signal" screen
- Monitor goes into power save mode
- Monitor comes out of power save
- Repeat

**Update 5**

I tried doing a safe boot; this also had no effect.

**Update 6**

Just for completeness I also used the external display's menu system to reset it to its factory defaults, but again, this had no effect.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Mac Mini 2012 with Thunderbolt display. Keeps waking up the external display. I thought I was crazy, but it seems that I am not the only one. Haven't found a solution, but thought you might want to know that it happens to me too.

Comment: I dont't own an iMac (I have a MacBook Air), but is the main display linked to the external display? What I mean is if the main display sleeps/dims, does the external display sleep?

Comment: When the main display sleeps/dims, the external display continually sleeps for a moment before waking up. That is the problem I'm trying to fix here.

Comment: Yes, I reset the SMC a couple of times.

Comment: Open System Preferences -> Energy Saving
Disable "Power Nap"
Report wether it still happens

Comment: Thanks, but this iMac does not support Power Nap, so there's nothing to enable or disable.

Comment: oh yeah, should have read better - my bad

Comment: one more,you could help us to help you by publishing your Console at the time stamp of the event, so we could see who and what is waking it up. while you at it also publish the configuration found under About this mac+more info+system report+Graphics display.. so to see if your system is correctly identifying the monitor ect.

Comment: @Buscar웃 see my update

Comment: I really don't know what the screenshot messages mean, it's not something that I've knowingly enabled. They show up any time the display sleeps.

Comment: For the other details I missed, no I don't have any kind of screen lock on the external display. It's connected via DisplayPort.

Comment: do you have a changing desktop background? Would that be worth turning off to see if it's at fault?

Comment: I don't, I have one static image that's the background on both displays.

Comment: Even though you say this monitor works as expected on another mac, have you tried a different Display port adaptor? Also, if you can manage it, take a look in the display port in the iMac itself, (using a jewelers loupe or magnifying glass with a strong light source,) to see if there is any obstuction

Comment: I don't have a different DisplayPort adapter, but working normally on a different Mac seems to rule that out anyway. I examined the port as suggested, and it looks good (I could see each individual pin, each clean and unobstructed, nothing remotely odd about the port).

Comment: Have you experimented using known-good adaptors, cables, etc, in an attempt to eliminate them from the problem chain? Sometimes physical damage can cause signal problems.

Answer (score 1):

Lets get more surgical here.

Facts are:
The external monitor stays in sleep mode on another Mac. It is unknowen if that mac has a Mavericks installed.

The Console report shows nothing unusual.

The Monitor configuration profile is still to be questioned (since it identifies the monitor as TV capable?

Recommended actions:

Use the PleaseSleep app
http://www.dragonone.com/products/macosx/pleasesleep/

---

Alternatively -Verify, Repair or replace the existing ICC profile

To verify use the Colorsync Utility and publish the current monitor profile

To repair use the ColorSyc utility and perform the repair of the external Monitors ICC

Alternatively download and install new ICC profile

New ICC profile for TFT monitor
http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/icc_profiles/nec_ea232wmi.icc

Comment: The other Mac is also running 10.9.2. I don't know what "Television: Yes" actually means in the system report, but for what it's worth both Macs show it that way. PleaseSleep didn't make any difference (but it seems to be about making the Mac sleep, not just the display). I verified, repaired, and finally replaced the profile, still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either of these commands to see if some process is preventing sleep?

pmset -g assertions

pmset -g log

Comment: System sleep isn't the problem, nor (I think) is internal display sleep. It's just the external display.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the energy saver option to "wake for network access".  Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

These steps will potentially help isolate hardware/software issues. Since the monitor and cables appear to work with another Mac, apparently it's a local hardware or software issue. You can restart and [perform a hardware test following these instructions from Apple](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) (complete test takes a few hours, run overnight) by holding d prior to chime on restart, disconnecting peripherals, etc.

Testing from a clean install on a known working partition will eliminate software. If that works good news! And, I'm sorry, as you're looking at an in place reinstall best case; or clean install... this is the last thing I ever want to hear as a suggestion. :) Have you tried an OS reinstall or clean install?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the system prefs -> power options then configure the sleep option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround.

I have a similar problem to the OP. I found that I can make the display sleep and stay asleep via the command line:

```
pmset displaysleepnow
```

In contrast, the external display wakes immediately after sleeping when I use the hot-corner method. Since display sleep problems can have many causes, my general advice is to try different methods of making the display sleep.